# How to migrate third party library to use jakarta.* import while upgrading spring 5.x to 6.x

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jakarta-migration

I'm upgrading my application to JDK17 and Spring 6.X, and I'm having trouble with some CutomFilter classes, which comes from a third-party library and internally implements the Filter class from javax.servlet.Filter, but when I upgraded to Spring 6, it expected Filter to be from Jakarta, how to transform 3rd party libraries, could you please help me with this if you have any ideas?

Comment: Unclear what exactly you're expecting from us as long as you don't tell which library exactly that "thirdPartyFilter" is coming from. Common sense is to just report issue at maintainers of "thirdPartyFilter" and/or to create a forked/patched version of it. That's up to you not to us.

Comment: That's true, We already sent a question to the maintainers and are waiting for a response, my concern is whether there is another way to make it function without updating third-party libraries.

Comment: If you are using Eclipse you can try Eclipse Transformer. IntelliJ had this built in I think.

Comment: I am using intellij , can you help me with the solution

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: updated my issue

Answer (score 0):

In that case what would I recommend is if modifying the third-party library is not an option, you can create your own   wrapper class that implements jakarta.servlet.Filter and delegates to the third-party library's javax.servlet.Filter implementation. This way, you can bridge the gap between the two interfaces .

In this wrapper class, you encapsulate an instance of the third-party library's javax.servlet.Filter implementation.

Hope this answers will give you some insights .